# Solving PDE with interesting initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I have the PDE (Fokker-Planck) which reads

$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial L}(L,x) = \bigg((x-1)^2\frac{\partial^2p}{\partial x^2}(L,x)+4x(x-1)\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}(L,x)+2xp(L,x)\bigg),$$
with initial condition $p(L=0,x)=\delta(x-1),$ where $\delta$ is a dirac delta function.

I'm looking for advice on the best way to solve this. Am I correct that the RHS of the PDE can be written as a Sturm-Louiville problem, and then some sort of transform can be used? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your restriction on $x$?

Comment: Sorry I should have said $x\in[0,1].$ I've thought about introducing a parameter $t$ say, so that $t\in[0,\infty).$

Answer (score 1):

Yes the right hand side can be written as a Sturm-Liouville equation, check out the [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%28x-1%29%5E2*y%27%27%20%2B%204*x*%28x-1%29*y%27%20%2B%202*x*y%3D0) solution! If you are interested in solving it yourself, then read below:

Particularly for the equilibrium distribution you may set the LHS to zero, then you have two options for solution:
1. because $x=1$ is a regular singular point of the differential equation, around which you may find a series expansion using Frobenius method, i.e. $p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n x^{n+\sigma}$ where $\sigma$ is a constant to be found.

2. Also, you will be able to convert the "RHS=0" into a hypergeometric differential equation for which analytical solutions exist, i.e. with the caveat that solutions are hypergeometric functions, yet they are very well known functions so that is no problem!